# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString return value is not reliable?

Tags: ios

I'm calling **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** while doing an async HTTP get operation in the callback for new bytes arriving.

But I know I don't know for sure, so I'm asking. What is the expected behavior?

And is **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** not executed synchronously, but actually run in a thread, which would be perilous for my purposes and would explain the empty response string... but not the valid response strings?

Lastly, is there any way to ask UIWebView whether it's busy and therefore cannot run  **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** reliably?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` blocks the thread that it runs on.  So, if you're not getting the desired output, you're doing something wrong.  Check your script.